# Is there protection against critical hits in League of legends?

Tags: league-of-legends

I know you can reduce the damage of critical hits in League of legends. (By masteries I think)

But there is something that can reduce the prob. of critical hit on an enemy?
If there is, can this affect yasuo's pasive?

Comment: Does blind, etc. count? Arguably, that reduces crit chance to 0, along with hit chance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there are no ways of lowering or increasing ones critical chance via spells (exception: Yasuo passive/Tryndamere passive). You can however lower the damage you take from critical strikes with masteries directly (x% less damage taken from critical strikes) as you already mentioned and also by buying armor or in case of a stattik shiv magic resistance.

If you just need more Survivability against critical strikes you will need armor, health and an attack speed slow since critical strike is usually bought by champions whose damage also depend on attack speed.

Answer (score 1):

Critical damage are `extra damage during an attack`. Besides they are physical damage (exception : static shiv). There is no particular protection per se against it.

All the way to reduce damage is a way to reduce critical damage as well. You can do it directly by getting:

- Armour
- Exhaust (-30% damage, -50% attack speed)
- Attack speed reduction
- Mastery

Another way to (indirectly) counter critical strikes would be :

- Health and shield (you gain time to kill/flee)
- Zhonya's Hourglass (can't be attacked)
- Kayle ultimate (absorb all damage)
- Thornail (reflects damage)
- Crowd control effects (stun, disable, blind etc)